# Nest in Excel the SUBSTITUTE FORMULA-ERROR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to nest a substitute formula. I tried to do the usual nest that is like substitute(substitute etc.

I keep getting an error and I cannot figure it out.

I have a text on `A1` cell, that I want to have on cell `J1`. The cell on `J1` has to be the text from `A1` after substitute the word "XXX" on that text for a the word(it will change many times) that is on `A4` cell, and the word "yyy" for a word that is on c4 cell, and the word "zzz" for a word that is on `E4` cell.

All these `A4`,`C4` and `E4` will change many times depending on the text that I will put.
The text to the `J1` must be the one with all this exchanges.

I already tried the formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "XXX", A4), "yyy", C4), "zzz", E4)
```

And i get the error that usually is generic" we found a problem with this formula. Try clicking insert function..."

Thanks to user jvdV its solved . It was a local settings and all the , had to be typed as a ;

Comment: most likely it's due to a typo, without having a look at your real formula it's not really possible to help you

Comment: I used the formula that is all over internet and not getting it. So frustrating
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "XXX", A4), "yyy", C4), "zzz", E4

Comment: Yes yes im sorry

Comment: and what is the error you keep getting? Instead of answering in a comment, please update your question, both adding your formula and the exact error.

Comment: Your error seems to be local settings dependent. Try chaning all "," to a ";"

Comment: JvdV and its solved . It was really that ,THANK YOU SO MUCH